# Render to another functional component based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have routes.js -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route , Link } from 'react-router';
import {BrowserRouter, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './Components/Login/SignIn';
import MainPage from './Components/MainPage';
function Routes() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/logout" component={SignIn} ></Route>
                <Route path="/home" component={MainPage} ></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Routes
```

Within SignIn.js I have button from which I want to render to main page.
Main bits of SignIn.Js are as below -

```
import MainPage from '../MainPage';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

 <FormGroup>
     <Button style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} onClick={NavigateToMainPage} >Sign in using our secure server</Button>
 </FormGroup>



function NavigateToMainPage(){
    let path = `/home`;
    let history = useHistory();
    history.push(path);
 }
```

This is not navigating.
How can I navigate on button click to another component in this case ?

Comment: Is this compiling? useHistory is a hook and can only be called in the main body of a Component

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this code isn't breaking completely because you can't use a hook outside of a react component, you can't use it in a normal function.

```
const Form = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  return <form>
    <button onClick={() => history.push('/home')}>Example</button>
  </form>
}
```

You want something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change how you call a function inside an `on click` prop.

If you write `onClick={functionName}`, the `functionName` would be always executed when the component is rendered and it would produce an infinite loop.

You have to change it into this `onClick={() => functionName()}` means that the `functionName` will be executed only after the the `onclick` is executed.

Don't forget to add `return` to the component.

Also if you use `hook` (like something starts from `use` word), you have to put it inside the functional component.

Here is the full code:

```js
import MainPage from '../MainPage';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const SignIn = () => {
    const NavigateToMainPage = () => {
        let path = `/home`;
        let history = useHistory();
        history.push(path);
    } 

    return(
        <FormGroup>
            <Button 
                style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} 
                onClick={() => NavigateToMainPage()} 
            >
                Sign in using our secure server
            </Button>
        </FormGroup>
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

Additional info:

1. I personally use `const` (ES6 arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) rather than `function` to declare a function.
2. In the MainPage.js, you can directly import the `Route`, `Switch`, and `Link` from `react-router-dom`.

So you can change it from this:

```js
import {Switch, Route , Link} from 'react-router';
import {BrowserRouter, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
```

into this:

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement your example using `NavLink` component instead of `useHistory` hook.

```
import MainPage from '../MainPage';
import { NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

 <FormGroup>
     <NavLink to="/home" style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} onClick={NavigateToMainPage}>Sign in using our secure server</NavLink>
 </FormGroup>
```

To top it off, please use `const` variables, forget about `var`.